# JS array of objects find by key and merge

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Have an array with objects, have find objects by `tenant_question_id` & `tenant_option_id` and have to merge `other1` & `other2` (which doesn't have `""`) and have unique obj in array

Input

```
[
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "22",
    other1: "$20,000.00",
    other2: ""
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "22",
    other1: "",
    other2: "on"
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "23",
    other1: "",
    other2: ""
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "23",
    other1: "$ 500.00",
    other2: ""
  }
]
```

Expected result

```
[
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "22",
    other1: "$20,000.00",
    other2: "on"
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "23",
    other1: "$ 500.00",
    other2: ""
  }
]
```

Tried `_.filter`, `_.omit` couldn't find it. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create an index by the key of `tenant_question_id` and `tenant_option_id` and merge the relevant properties on each iteration. Then simply take the values of the index and there you go.

```js
let tenants = [{
  tenant_question_id: "3",
  tenant_option_id: "22",
  other1: "$ 20,000.00",
  other2: ""
}, {
  tenant_question_id: "3",
  tenant_option_id: "22",
  other1: "",
  other2: "on"
}, {
  tenant_question_id: "3",
  tenant_option_id: "23",
  other1: "",
  other2: ""
}, {
  tenant_question_id: "3",
  tenant_option_id: "23",
  other1: "$ 500.00",
  other2: ""
}];
let result = {};

for (item of tenants) {
  let key = item.tenant_question_id + ";" + item.tenant_option_id;
  if (key in result) {
    const properties = ["other1", "other2"];
    for (property of properties) {
      if (item[property]) {
        result[key][property] = item[property];
      }
    }
  } else {
    result[key] = Object.assign(item);
  }
}
result = Object.values(result);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
const mergedData = input.reduce((resultArray, tenantData) => {
  const index = resultArray.findIndex(entry => entry.tenant_question_id === tenantData.tenant_question_id && entry.tenant_option_id === tenantData.tenant_option_id);
  if (index!==-1) {
    const existingData = resultArray[index];
    if (!existingData.other1) {
      existingData.other1 = tenantData.other1;
    }
    if (!existingData.other2) {
      existingData.other2 = tenantData.other2;
    }
  } else {
    resultArray.push(tenantData);
  }
  return resultArray;
}, []);
```

Basically iterating over the array and gradually populating a resulting array. For each item check if an item with the tenant_question_id and tenant_option_id already exists, if it does, we'll overwrite other1 and other2 if they have a falsey value ("") on the existing object. If it doesn't exist, we push the current object.

This does have the problem that if there are several objects with the same option and key that have either both other2 or both other1 set to a non-string value, the latest value in the iterated list will be used. I'm assuming your data set does not contain such entries.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the [crocks](https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks) and [ramda](https://ramdajs.com) functional libraries, you can do this in a more-or-less declarative style.

```js
const { groupWith, eqProps, equals } = R
const { assign, map, reduce, compose } = crocks

const data = [
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "22", other1: "$ 20,000.00", other2: ""},
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "22", other1: "", other2: "on"},
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "23", other1: "", other2: ""},
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "23", other1: "$ 500.00", other2: ""}
];

const expected = [
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "22", other1: "$ 20,000.00", other2: "on"},
  {tenant_question_id: "3", tenant_option_id: "23", other1: "$ 500.00", other2: ""}
];

// This could be composed of entries, fromEntries, and filter,
// but this approach saves an iteration.
const stripFalsyValues = t =>
  Object.entries(t)
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, ...(v && {[k]: v})}), {})

const mergeAll = reduce(assign, {})

const isSameTenantOptionId = eqProps('tenant_option_id')

const groupByTenantOptionId = groupWith(isSameTenantOptionId)

const mergeTenants = compose(
  map(mergeAll),
  groupByTenantOptionId,
  map(stripFalsyValues)
)

const result = mergeTenants(data)


console.log({expected, result})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/crocks/dist/crocks.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha256-YN22NHB7zs5+LjcHWgk3zL0s+CRnzCQzDOFnndmUamY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note, with regards to the missing `other2: ""` in the second result object, that could be handled at the edge with default properties for UI purposes. If you absolutely must pass on the empty string, you could compose together some `assignWhen = when(undefinedOption2, assign({option2: ""})`

Answer (score 0):

I've just made this, it returns exactly the output you wanted.

```js
var data = [{
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "22",
    other1: "$20,000.00",
    other2: ""
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "22",
    other1: "",
    other2: "on"
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "23",
    other1: "",
    other2: ""
  },
  {
    tenant_question_id: "3",
    tenant_option_id: "23",
    other1: "$ 500.00",
    other2: ""
  }
];

data = data.map(function(item, index, arr) {

  // We remove the current mapped item from arr(self)
  // So we can search within an arr that doesn't contain our "item" at the "index" position
  arr.splice(index, 1);

  if (item.other2 === '') {

    var weFoundAnother = arr.find(function(elem, idx) {
      return elem.tenant_question_id === item.tenant_question_id &&
        elem.tenant_option_id === item.tenant_option_id &&
        elem.other2.length;
    });

    if (weFoundAnother !== undefined) {

      // We found our element and now we'll remove this too from "arr"
      // Let's get "weFoundAnother" index first using 
      //  -> arr.indexOf(weFoundAnother)
      // Then we can remove it from "arr" because it is used now.
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(weFoundAnother), 1);

      item.other2 = weFoundAnother.other2;

    }

  }

  return item;

  // Now we'll filter the empty slots ( items that we removed )
  // And that's it

}).filter(function(i) {
  return i !== undefined
})

console.clear();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```